How to loop a number of cells to take up data when a particular cell is triggered
I want a loop in this code to enter data in the cells C2, D2, E2, and F2 immediately the cell A2 is clicked or triggered. (The code below is able to this).
The cells, C3, D3, E3, and F3 should also take up data immediately cell A3 is clicked.
This should be the same for C4, D4, E4, and F4 when A4 is clicked.
This should continue.
This should be the sequence for inputting data in the cells within the range C2:F5
(The total from C2, D2, E2, and F2 should not exceed the value in B2)
Also, if possible, the dates captured in cells C2, D2, E2, and F2 should be displayed on the "InputBox" respectively to be cautious of the date and amount keyed.
Sample table:



A
B
C
D
E
F




1
Name of Member
Total Cont.
5th Nov. 23
12th Nov. 23
19th Nov. 23


2
Daniel Harry
300.00
100.00
50.00
29.00


3
Adams Hey






4
Ayoti Kabri






5
Adams Ford







Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Const iAddress As String = "A2:A5" 'Loopfor cells A3 to A5
    Const mrgAddress As String = "C2,D2,E2,F2" 'Keep merged cell range unchanged
                    
    Dim iCell As Range
    
    Set iCell = Intersect(Range(iAddress), Target)
    If iCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim mrg As Range: Set mrg = Range(mrgAddress)
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim varEintrag As Variant
    
    For Each iCell In mrg.Cells
        
        varEintrag = Application.InputBox( _
          Prompt:="Enter Amount to '" & iCell.Address(0, 0) _
          & "' then press Enter:", _
          Title:="AMOUNT TO PAY FOR THIS WEEK", _
          Default:=iCell.value)
    
        If varEintrag <> "Falsch" And varEintrag <> "False" Then
            If IsNumeric(varEintrag) Then
                iCell.value = CDbl(varEintrag)
            Else
                iCell.value = varEintrag
            End If
        Else
            Exit For ' Cancel
        End If
    
    Next iCell

SafeExit:
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True

    Exit Sub

ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub


Set mrg = Target.EntireRow.Range("C1:F1")  Here Range() is relative to Target.EntireRow

Try this out:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const iAddress As String = "A2:A5" 'Loopfor cells A3 to A5
    Const mrgAddress As String = "C1:F1" 'Keep merged cell range unchanged
                    
    Dim iCell As Range, mrg As Range
    Dim varEintrag As Variant
    
    'do we need to handle this selection?
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Me.Range(iAddress), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    Set mrg = Target.EntireRow.Range(mrgAddress) ' `Range` is *relative* to the row...
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'only need this if you also have a "Change" event handler?
    For Each iCell In mrg.Cells
        
        varEintrag = Application.InputBox( _
            prompt:="Enter Amount to '" & iCell.Address(0, 0) _
                & "' then press Enter:", _
            Title:="AMOUNT TO PAY FOR WEEK: " & Me.Cells(1, iCell.Column).Value, _
            Default:=iCell.Value)
    
        If varEintrag <> "Falsch" And varEintrag <> "False" Then
            If IsNumeric(varEintrag) Then varEintrag = CDbl(varEintrag)
            iCell.Value = varEintrag
        Else
            Exit For ' Cancel
        End If
    Next iCell

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub


Good morning Tim Williams, thanks so much for your time and wanting to help me out. I really appreciate it. But, I am not able to run the code. This line "Set mrg = Target.EntireRow.Range(mrgAddress) "range is relative to the row..." turned red immeditely in inserted it into the module. Please help once more

"range is *relative* to the row... is a comment, change the double quote "to a single quote '
